# Неверное время в MySQLзапросе

Tags: mysql, база-данных

У меня есть БД с данными о резервировании жилья. Каждая запись имеет дату заявки (поле reservated). 
Задача: удалить все заявки, которым более чем 1 сутки и которые не прошли одобрение (поле approve)

Использовал такой запрос:

```
 DELETE FROM table
        WHERE approve=''
        AND DATE (reservated) NOT BETWEEN DATE( DATE_SUB( NOW() , INTERVAL 24 HOUR ) ) AND DATE ( NOW() )
```

Но он удаляет из БД все записи, которые старше не на 24 часа, а на 2 дня.

Пример:
сегодня 6 марта 18:00
По идее, после отправки запроса должны удалиться все записи до 5 марта 18:00
Но удаляются все записи до 4 марта 23:59

Что я сделал не так? 
Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Comment: *Пример: сегодня 6 марта 18:00*: `NOW()` = `6 марта 18:00`, `DATE_SUB( NOW() , INTERVAL 24 HOUR )` = `5 марта 18:00`, `DATE( DATE_SUB( NOW() , INTERVAL 24 HOUR ) )` = `5 марта (00:00)`.

Answer (score 0):

Для начала надо посмотреть, что выдает запрос через SELECT.

Возможно, надо исправить запрос таким образом:

```
DELETE FROM table
        WHERE approve=''
        AND DATE (reservated) NOT BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW() , INTERVAL 24 HOUR )  AND DATE ( NOW() )
```

Напишите, если помогло :)

Comment: Не помогло. Но я сделал другим способом, упростив запрос) ведь дата резервирования у меня в том же формате, что и время, посему не было необходимости переводить все эти значения в дату.
Вот такой запрос сработал вполне)

`DELETE FROM wp_reservations1
 WHERE approve=''
 AND (reservated) NOT BETWEEN DATE_SUB( NOW() , INTERVAL 24 HOUR )  AND  NOW()`